# Why the objects are not drawing when i check collision?

Tags: java, collision

Hi I am trying to create a space invaders game and I have a problem with the collision between a missile and an enemy. I created a function that checks the collision using the intersects method from rectangle but when I call it in the update method of enemy the missiles are not launching from the player correctly and I can't figure out why.

```
//enemy class
public void checkCollisions(){

   for(int i=0;i<GameFrame.getMissileList().size();i++){

       Missile m = GameFrame.getMissileList().get(i);

       if(getBounds().intersects(m.getBounds()))
           GameFrame.removeEnemy(this);
           GameFrame.removeMissile(m);
   }
}
```

//the method getbounds of rectangle

```
public Rectangle getBounds()
{ return new 
Rectangle(x,y,getEnemyImg().getWidth(null),getEnemyImg().getHeight(null));
}
```

//

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    player.update();
    repaint();

    for(int i=0; i<enemies.size();i++)
    {
        Enemy tempEnemy = enemies.get(i);
        tempEnemy.update();
    }

    for(int i=0; i < missiles.size();i++)
    {
        Missile m = missiles.get(i);
        m.update();

    }

    repaint();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but you're creating a new Rectangle for every missile collision check.

Comment: What is the actual problem?  The collision not working or missiles not launching correctly?

Comment: Maybe the missile is never *actually* intersecting enemy when this is calculated. Imagine it in stop-motion: the missile, especially if it is moving fast, might *skip past the enemy between collision calculations* and its current position, at the time of calculation, won't be intersecting the enemy. You might have to check if the line from the previous position of the missile to its current position passes through the current rectangle of the enemy.

Comment: the problem is that the missiles are not launching at all, but if i do not use the checkcollision they are launching but obviously they are going through the enemies

Comment: Are your missiles perchance colliding with the launcher?

Comment: @xtratic no the player launch them and the enemies are falling down from the top and the missiles should collide with the enemies

Comment: i solved this :D actually i forgot to put {} in if(getBounds().intersects(m.getBounds()))
           GameFrame.removeEnemy(this);
           GameFrame.removeMissile(m);

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that either... Why was it indented like that? Use an IDE and code formatter so it indents properly so you can find these issues more easily.